# how can i resolve this error in below code

Tags: bash, syntax-error

Hello i have written a bash script to make "automation" installation process for myself, to i am avoiding everytime when i install kali linux f.e. to do it manually. I change from if statements to functions and case. So i got 2 error:

```
4ut0m4t10n.sh: line 544: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
```

And this error:

```
4ut0m4t10n.sh: line 580: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I am not sure, if i should post all lines of it here, so it keeps much time to read the code (i am beginner). We have here formatting options so some characters of my script won't print, i will list the error lines, and the rest of it in a pastebin.

https://pastebin.com/yrDMMSVN

Error lines(while is line 544):

```
while [ $x = 0 ]
do
    clear
    echo '【 mak3r@root 】~>: '
    read ex
    case "$ex" in
        full_config)
        full_config
        x=1
        ;;
        install_tools)
        install_tools
        x=1
        ;;
        social_media)
        social_media
        x=1
        ;;
        cmd_crtr)
        cmd_crtr
        x=1
        ;;
        credits)
        credits
        x=1
        ;;
        quit)
        quit
        x=1
        ;;
        q)
        x=1
        echo 'Exiting..'
        sleep 0.5
        ;;
        *)
        echo '[!] Wrong command!'
        sleep 1
        ;;
    esac
done
```

line 580 here.

**Thanks in advance my friends**

Comment: A good place to start is http://shellcheck.net/. Also, see [mre] guidelines -- removing all the parts of your script that *aren't* necessary to cause the problem makes it easier for folks to answer, and easier for others to learn from those answers.

Comment: That said, the subset of the script you posted here does not, on its own, cause any syntax error. And we *do* require the code in the question to *actually cause the error*; links that are supplemental information are welcome, but questions (and their answers) need to be understandable without them, or if they break.

Comment: ...paste your entire script into http://shellcheck.net/, and it tells you that the first syntax error is at line 481, before the `while` loop included in the question text even starts.

Comment: You can shorten the code with a single case: `full_config|install_tools|social_media|cmd_crtr|quit) "$ex"; x=1; ;;`

Comment: Thank you all. I will check out the website

Comment: You will find using ASNI escapes or `tput` for colors in scripts is a close call on whether it is more trouble than it is worth. It does add a bit of "nicety" to the output, but chasing a closing-brace error from line 461 for a color issue shows the downside. More code -- more room for human error..

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo -e "${GREEN[*]${BLUE}Do you want to generate a password for your own security?[Y/N]?: "
```

You have not closed `{` here.